# How to hist plot list of list in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a list of lists as follows.

```
import random
list_of_list=[]

for i in range(1000):
    sub_list=[random.randint(0, 10) for iter in range(10)]
    list_of_list.append(sub_list)
```

​
I am able to plot any single sublist of the  above list of lists as follows with a hist plot.

```
plt.hist(list_of_list[10])
```

[image: Single sublist plot]

Is there anyway I can plot this whole list of list in histogram or any other similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a list of lists will treat every sublist as a separate group, differentiated by color.

```
plt.hist(list_of_list)
```

Example for 3 sublists:

[image]

If you want, you can also flatten the sublists into a single list so they are all treated as the same batch:

```
import itertools
merged = list(itertools.chain(*list_of_list))
plt.hist(merged)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can plot it as

```py
plt.hist([elt for lst in list_of_list for elt in lst])
```

[image: example hist]

You'll note that the height of the last bin is the double of the rest. Unlike similar functions, `random.randint(0, 10)` generates values from `0` to `10` inclusive. Due to rounding, both `9` and `10` end up in the same bin. You can create 11 bins with `plt.hist(..., bins=11)`.

Also note that when working with large lists of numerical data, it is always much easier and faster to employ the [numpy](https://numpy.org/) library. It's syntax may look weird at first, but you quickly get used to it.  For example to create a 1d list from your 2d list, the command would be `np.array(list_of_list).ravel()`.